# UIImagePickerController strange status bar

Tags: xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Does anyone know what is this strange white bar on the top of a UIImagePickerController?
I'm presenting it from my EditProfileViewController, when it appears modally it comes with that strange white bar in the top of the navBar.

I've managed to take the print screen below:

[image]

How can I get rid of it?

Is it something to do with the UIImagePickerController statusBar?

Answer (score 0):

That bar  white bar is the background for the status bar at the top of the screen. It's a bit crude, but the best workaround I found was to disable the status bar right before I present my view and then enable it again once the user has picked an image and the imagepicker has disappeared again.

This is how you hide/show it:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than answer.